# Passing Custom Attribute in AuthRequest and use as Input Claims to Custom Policy with SAML SP Initiated Flow

Tags: saml, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to integrate Azure B2C as the IDP with a number of legacy applications using SAML SP initiated Flow where I need to pass as attribute with the AuthRequest which I will use in a service call during login from within the custom policy.

I am wondering is there a way to use the relay state for this or does Azure B2C support SAML Extensions to support this use case?

I know I can do this with OIDC but my applications do not support this currently :(.

Kind Regards,
Lastbuilders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try passing the value in the relay state parameter from SP Initiated flow and then reading it using `{SAML:RelayState}`claim resolver within the policy.

Comment: Thanks Razi, I will try that. I did not think that was available it as it is not one of the reference claims here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claim-resolver-overview